# Raise unhandlable exception in Python

Tags: python-3.x, exception, raise

I have a Python program that handles (excepts) all the exceptions raised by external files. I want an exception that will be thrown from the try block and except will not silence it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2.7 you can just do the following. I'm not sure about python 3.x but I would assume it is the same.

```
try:
    # something
except IOError:
    # display error
except:
    raise
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have a utility that tolds you where the error occoured and asks you if you want to display it. I want to display automatically specific errors (such as `IOError`)

Comment: In the except clause you can name what exception you want to target, look at my edit.